# PCA in OpenCV and how to prepare data?

Tags: opencv, pca

I just want to clarify something about PCA in OpenCV. Suppose, I have two rows of data (A, B).

A   3   8   7

B   2   4   5

If I wanted to create a PCA model in OpenCV, what must I do to the data? Do I have to subtract the means (e.g. subtract the mean of A from its data points) or does the PCA function do this?

Someone said that OpenCV PCA expects the data to be normalised (between 0 and 1). If so, how do I normalise?

Hope someone can clarify this for me as PCA in OpenCV is very badly documented on the Net.

Cheers...

Answer (score 3):

The data for PCA in OpenCV needs **not** to be normalized. But if you already have the mean (from some previuos calculations), you can send it to the PCACompute() function to speed it up.

OpenCV refman:

> PCACompute(data[, mean[, eigenvectors[, maxComponents ]]]) !mean, eigenvectors
>   Parameters
>
> - data – Input samples stored as the matrix rows or as the matrix columns.
> - mean – Optional mean value. If the matrix is empty ( noArray() ), the mean is computed
>     from the data.

There is a good article on data normalization [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29).

For complete documentation check out the opencv.pdf file that should be in the doc/ folder of your instalation. On some versions it is named opencv2refman.pdf

And also try to find the book "Learning OpenCV", by Gary Bradsky, it's more than well exlained.